# Java-JPA: Is it possible to map two relationships between two entities by more tables depending on a value a field has in one of the fields?

Tags: java, jpa

The idea that raised this question is the following:

Each User has an active cart and a history of purchased/finalized carts.

I know there might be logical/reasoning flaws in my approach so I'm basically just asking if this is doable: Is it possible to have the 2 separate tables for the list of carts which contains carts with a certain value in the status field? I'd like for a cart to be in a certain table while status is active and to move to the other table once it's finalized.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    class User{
        @Id
        private Long id;
        @OneToOne
        private ShoppingCart activeCart;
        @OneToMany
        private List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartHistory;
           //getters setters
    }
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "carts")
    class ShoppingCart{
        @Id
        Long id;
        private List<String> items;
        private String status;
        //getters setters
    }
```

Comment: Why not give each user one cart, and a list of `Orders` for completed orders.

Comment: To be honest we already figured keeping history items separate as Order objects would be better but I'm just curious if what I asked above is even possible. Not sure anyone would ever need it but I really couldn't find an answer as to whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You'd like to both maintain a `status` field AND keep `ShoppingCarts` with different statuses in separate tables? Don't you think that's redundant? Just create an additional `@OneToMany private List<ShoppingCart> completedShoppingCarts` field and move the `ShoppingCarts` between the two collections when status changes.